# Need advice on customizing ListBox template

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, listbox, itemspaneltemplate

I have a ListBox of CheckBox values, the number of values vary from time to time, it can be 10, 15, 100, etc..

I would like to customize the way the values are displayed. Currently, if I have 50 values, they are all displayed vertically, just one column.

I would like to have it such that, 1 column will have a maximum of 10 values, and I am able to scroll horizontally to view the values at other columns.

I tried using ItemsPanelTemplate with StackPanel orientation horizontal, but well, all values are now in 1 row.

Please advice.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try changing the panel used by your `ListBox` to a `WrapPanel` instead. Set its `Orientation` to `Vertical`, then size the height of the `ListBox` so it fits 10 items in each "column" before starting a new column.

```
<ListBox Height="..."
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
</ListBox>
```

If you want 10 items in each column but don't want to explicitly set the height of the `ListBox` then the only solution I can think of is writing a custom `Panel`.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working, set the listbox height and width to be 300, with wrappanel vertical, all values are displayed in a row with no scrollbar.

If I set the wrappanel orientation to horizontal, all values are displayed in a column, with a vertical scrollbar.

Comment: Sorry about that! Should have tested before posting. The reason is because a `ListBox` control's template includes a `ScrollViewer` which has its horizontal scrollbar hidden. Try setting the `ScrollViewer` attached properties to change the scroll bar behaviour, as shown in my modified XAML code.